# Create all cross combinations, respecting the column hierarchy

Tags: r, data.table, cross-join

From my `data.table` *DT.in*, I want to create all cross join combinations, but not only `CJ(_all_my_var_)`.

I need to perform something like this :

```
CJ(var1)
CJ(var1, var2)
CJ(var1, var2, var3)
...
```

Here is my reprex :

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(999)

DT.in <- data.table(lvl1 = rep('AA', 200),
                 code = sample(c('D44', 'J21'), 200, replace = TRUE),
                 var = sample(c('Z3R', 'TR5', 'JKL', 'FR5', 'TFX'), 200, replace = TRUE),
                 test = sample(c('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 'SIX', 'SEVEN'), 200, replace = TRUE))

foo.1 <- DT.in[, .(new = CJ(lvl1, unique = TRUE))]
foo.2 <- DT.in[, .(new = CJ(lvl1, code, unique = TRUE))]
foo.3 <- DT.in[, .(new = CJ(lvl1, code, var, unique = TRUE))]
foo.4 <- DT.in[, .(new = CJ(lvl1, code, var, test, unique = TRUE))]

DT.out <- rbindlist(list(foo.1, foo.2, foo.3, foo.4), fill = TRUE)
```

My *DT.out* is what I want, but of course, I need to automate this, the name and the number of variable are never the same. And I still can't do it ...

Any help to do this will be very appreciated.

(Maybe there is a whole other way to go from DT.in to DT.out ...?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `do.call` with [`CJ`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/J)

1. Loop over the sequence of columns of 'DT.in' with `lapply`
2. Get the `seq`uence, to select the columns based on the numeric index
3. Apply the `CJ` in `do.call`
4. Bind the output datasets in the `list` to a single one with `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
DT.out2 <- rbindlist(lapply(seq_along(DT.in), function(i) 
      do.call(CJ, c(DT.in[, seq(i), with = FALSE], unique = TRUE))), fill = TRUE)
setnames(DT.out2, paste0("new.", names(DT.out2)))
```

-checking with OP's output

```
identical(DT.out, DT.out2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Wouhou such impressive and what a quick answer !! And thanks for the details.